# SQL. Find the first and last value in a time interval, and then work with them

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Today I have started to optimize different procedures of the database in SQL Server.

I would like to know if you can help me to optimize the following query:

```
DECLARE @fkTipoDato INTEGER = 8;
DECLARE @fkPlanta INTEGER = 1;
DECLARE @FechaInicio DATETIME = CAST('2020-27-10 00:00:00' AS DATETIME);
DECLARE @FechaFin DATETIME = CAST('2020-28-10 00:00:00' AS DATETIME);
DECLARE @FechaWhile DATETIME = @FechaInicio;
DECLARE @valorMaximoMedidor REAL = 2999999;
DECLARE @TablaTemp TABLE (
    tempFecha VARCHAR(20)
    ,cero REAL
    ,uno REAL
    ,dos REAL
    ,tres REAL
    ,cuatro REAL
    ,cinco REAL
    ,seis REAL
    ,siete REAL
    ,ocho REAL
    ,nueve REAL
    ,diez REAL
    ,ONCE REAL
    ,doce REAL
    ,trece REAL
    ,catorce REAL
    ,quince REAL
    ,dieciseis REAL
    ,diecisiete REAL
    ,dieciocho REAL
    ,diecinueve REAL
    ,veinte REAL
    ,veintiuno REAL
    ,veintidos REAL
    ,veintitres REAL
    );

WHILE @FechaWhile <= @FechaFin
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ValorFinal0 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= CAST(@FechaWhile AS DATETIME)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial0 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= CAST(@FechaWhile AS DATETIME)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal1 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 2, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial1 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 2, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal2 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 2, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 3, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial2 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 2, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 3, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal3 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 3, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 4, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial3 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 3, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 4, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal4 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 4, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 5, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial4 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 4, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 5, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal5 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 5, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 6, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial5 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 5, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 6, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal6 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 6, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 7, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial6 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 6, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 7, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal7 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 7, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 8, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial7 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 7, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 8, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal8 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 8, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 9, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial8 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 8, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 9, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal9 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 9, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 10, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial9 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 9, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 10, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal10 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 10, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 11, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial10 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 10, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 11, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal11 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 11, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 12, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial11 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 11, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 12, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal12 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 12, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 13, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial12 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 12, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 13, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal13 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 13, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 14, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial13 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 13, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 14, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal14 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 14, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 15, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial14 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 14, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 15, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal15 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 15, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 16, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial15 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 15, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 16, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal16 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 16, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 17, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial16 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 16, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 17, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal17 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 17, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 18, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial17 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 17, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 18, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal18 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 18, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 19, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial18 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 18, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 19, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal19 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 19, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 20, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial19 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 19, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 20, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal20 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 20, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 21, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial20 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 20, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 21, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal21 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 21, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 22, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial21 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 21, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 22, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal22 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 22, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 23, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial22 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 22, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 23, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorFinal23 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 23, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 24, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora DESC
            );
    DECLARE @ValorInicial23 REAL = (
            SELECT TOP 1 valor
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 23, @FechaWhile)
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, - 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 24, @FechaWhile))
            ORDER BY FechaHora ASC
            );

    IF EXISTS (
            SELECT TOP 1 FechaHora
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                AND FechaHora >= @FechaWhile
                AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(day, 1, @FechaWhile)
                AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
            )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @TablaTemp
        SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FechaHora, 103) AS [Fecha]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal0 >= @ValorInicial0
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal0 - @ValorInicial0)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial0) + @ValorFinal0)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [00:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal1 >= @ValorInicial1
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal1 - @ValorInicial1)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial1) + @ValorFinal1)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [01:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal2 >= @ValorInicial2
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal2 - @ValorInicial2)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial2) + @ValorFinal2)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [02:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal3 >= @ValorInicial3
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal3 - @ValorInicial3)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial3) + @ValorFinal3)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [03:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal4 >= @ValorInicial4
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal4 - @ValorInicial4)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial4) + @ValorFinal4)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [04:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal5 >= @ValorInicial5
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal5 - @ValorInicial5)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial5) + @ValorFinal5)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [05:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal6 >= @ValorInicial6
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal6 - @ValorInicial6)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial6) + @ValorFinal6)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [06:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal7 >= @ValorInicial7
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal7 - @ValorInicial7)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial7) + @ValorFinal7)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [07:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal8 >= @ValorInicial8
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal8 - @ValorInicial8)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial8) + @ValorFinal8)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [08:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal9 >= @ValorInicial9
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal9 - @ValorInicial9)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial9) + @ValorFinal9)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [09:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal10 >= @ValorInicial10
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal10 - @ValorInicial10)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial10) + @ValorFinal10)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [10:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal11 >= @ValorInicial11
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal11 - @ValorInicial11)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial11) + @ValorFinal11)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [11:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal12 >= @ValorInicial12
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal12 - @ValorInicial12)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial12) + @ValorFinal12)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [12:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal13 >= @ValorInicial13
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal13 - @ValorInicial13)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial13) + @ValorFinal13)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [13:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal14 >= @ValorInicial14
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal14 - @ValorInicial14)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial14) + @ValorFinal14)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [14:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal15 >= @ValorInicial15
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal15 - @ValorInicial15)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial15) + @ValorFinal15)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [15:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal16 >= @ValorInicial16
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal16 - @ValorInicial16)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial16) + @ValorFinal16)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [16:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal17 >= @ValorInicial17
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal17 - @ValorInicial17)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial17) + @ValorFinal17)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [17:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal18 >= @ValorInicial18
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal18 - @ValorInicial18)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial18) + @ValorFinal18)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [18:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal19 >= @ValorInicial19
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal19 - @ValorInicial19)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial19) + @ValorFinal19)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [19:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal20 >= @ValorInicial20
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal20 - @ValorInicial20)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial20) + @ValorFinal20)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [20:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal21 >= @ValorInicial21
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal21 - @ValorInicial21)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial21) + @ValorFinal21)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [21:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal22 >= @ValorInicial22
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal22 - @ValorInicial22)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial22) + @ValorFinal22)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [22:00]
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN @ValorFinal23 >= @ValorInicial23
                        THEN (
                                SELECT (@ValorFinal23 - @ValorInicial23)
                                )
                    ELSE (
                            SELECT ((@valorMaximoMedidor - @ValorInicial23) + @ValorFinal23)
                            )
                    END
                ) AS [23:00]
        FROM RegistroDatos
        WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
            AND FechaHora >= @FechaWhile
            AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(day, 1, @FechaWhile)
            AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
    END

    SET @FechaWhile = DATEADD(day, 1, @FechaWhile);
END

SELECT tempFecha AS [Fecha]
    ,cero AS [00:00]
    ,uno AS [01:00]
    ,dos AS [02:00]
    ,tres AS [03:00]
    ,cuatro AS [04:00]
    ,cinco AS [05:00]
    ,seis AS [06:00]
    ,siete AS [07:00]
    ,ocho AS [08:00]
    ,nueve AS [09:00]
    ,diez AS [10:00]
    ,ONCE AS [11:00]
    ,doce AS [12:00]
    ,trece AS [13:00]
    ,catorce AS [14:00]
    ,quince AS [15:00]
    ,dieciseis AS [16:00]
    ,diecisiete AS [17:00]
    ,dieciocho AS [18:00]
    ,diecinueve AS [19:00]
    ,veinte AS [20:00]
    ,veintiuno AS [21:00]
    ,veintidos AS [22:00]
    ,veintitres AS [23:00]
FROM @TablaTemp
```

It returns the consumptions (difference between maximum and minimum value) separated by hours and days (which would be easy to do), but the problem appears since when data is saved and the value = 2999999 is reached, the counter is reset. So you should check the first and last values instead of the minimum and maximum, and then work with them.

As well as attach the code, it works, but it is slow.

VERSION: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM)

The RegistroDatos table has the following layout:
[image: DDL]
[image: RegistroDatos Design]

[image: RegistroDatos]

Any suggestion?

Comment: At a glance, get rid of all of the -1ms code and replace the comparison operator `<=` with `<`. And get rid of all the spurious `select`s. `(select(@ValorFinal7-@ValorInicial7))` is just `@ValorFinal7-@ValorInicial7`.

Comment: so I'm sure there is a single select statement to do this using windowing but I have no idea what you are doing -- can you explain what you are doing and give example starting data and results?

Comment: Please add the DDL, including any indexes, for `RegistroDatos` to your post.

Comment: @HABO Done, add as requested

Comment: I have removed all the -1ms and the select's (@ValorFinalx - @ValorInicialx), but the delay of the query remains the same

Comment: If you would update the query in your post, the reduced visual noise might let us see things more easily. (I didn't expect a significant change in performance. It's just hard to read past all of the unnecessary code.) Adding a _single_ index to `RegistroDatos` on `fk_TipoDato`, `fk_Planta` and `FechaHora` (in that order) and a second index on `fk_TipoDato`, `fk_Planta` and `FechaHora desc`should help performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not test the code because you posted your DDL as image not as text. But I think I get the idea of what you try to achieve.
You're executing the same query multiple times so doing all the work in a single pass should improve the execution time.

```
WITH timeParts AS (
    /* Get the date and hour parts as independent columns
        to simplify expressions down the line */
    SELECT
        FechaHora, Valor,
        CAST(FechaHora AS DATE) AS [date],      --Truncate time part
        DATEPART([HOUR], FechaHora) AS [hour]
    FROM
        dbo.RegistroDatos
    WHERE
        fk_TipoDato   = @fkTipoDato
        AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
        AND FechaHora >= CAST(@FechaInicio AS DATETIME)
        AND FechaHora < DATEADD([DAY], 1, CAST(@FechaFin AS DATETIME))
),
firstAndLast AS (
    /* generate sequences to identify the first and last "valor" values */
    SELECT
        [date], [hour],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [date], [hour] ORDER BY FechaHora) AS firstR,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [date], [hour] ORDER BY FechaHora DESC) AS lastR,
        Valor
    FROM
        timeParts
),
firstPass AS (
    /*  Put initial and last values side by side to simplify the comsumption calculation,
        basically a pivot operation */
SELECT
    [date], [hour],
    MIN(CASE WHEN firstR = 1 THEN Valor END) AS initialValue,
    MIN(CASE WHEN lastR  = 1 THEN Valor END) AS finalValue
FROM
    firstAndLast
GROUP BY
    [date], [hour]
),
consumptions AS (
    /*  Having every value needed side by side simplifies the code:
        you don't need to repeat 24 times the same code... */
    SELECT
        [date], [hour],
        CASE
            WHEN finalValue >= initialValue THEN finalValue - initialValue
            ELSE @valorMaximoMedidor - initialValue + finalValue
        END AS consumption
    FROM
        firstPass
)
SELECT *
FROM
    consumptions
PIVOT(MIN(consumption) FOR [hour] IN (
     [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9],[10],[11],
    [12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23])) pvt;
```

An appropriate index for your query would improve the execution time even further if it does not exists already:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON dbo.RegistroDatos(FechaHora, fk_Planta, fk_TipoDato)
INCLUDE(Valor);
```

Comment: Many thanks!!! This solved my problem. Low query time from 2 min to 2 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a set based solution.  I would start with GROUP BY on CAST(FechaHora as date), DATEPART(HOUR, FechaHora).  Group on other columns if required.  MIN and MAX are easy.  First and last are more difficult.  If you have a monotonically increasing or decreasing value that unique, it can be used to get a "key" to the first and last records in each group.  FechaHora might work for this if there is nothing else.  Otherwise, I would try a solution using the windows functions FIRST() and LAST().

```
    SELECT CAST(FechaHora as date) as [FechaHora_date], 
        DATEPART(HOUR, FechaHora) as [FechaHora_hour],
        MIN(valor) as [valor_min],
        MAX(valor) as [valor_max],
        MAX(valor) - MIN(valor) as [Consumption],
        MIN(id) as [id_min], -- is there a min value the identifies the first record?
        MAX(id) as [id_max], -- is there a max value the identifies the last record?
    FROM RegistroDatos
    WHERE FechaHora BETWEEN @FechaInicio AND @FechaFin
    GROUP BY CAST(FechaHora as date), DATEPART(HOUR, FechaHora)
```

If you need to use the first and last records, then join to RegistroDatosto on id_min and then again on id_max to get the value of valor for both.

If you need records for where there is no data, you can generate a numbers table to create a table with all the dates and hours required.  Then join to it with the data, replacing nulls with zero if needed.

Comment: In the post add the format of the table RegistroDatos